# Does the below imply hearing his brusqueness for the first time, or hearing a higher degree of his brusqueness?

Tags: grammar

Does the below imply hearing his brusqueness for the first time, or hearing a higher degree of his brusqueness?

> His tone was brusque like never before.

Comment: Could be either. More context will clarify.

Comment: I think if the author intended "like never before" to mean the person had never been brusque before, then it would be bad writing even though it's logically possible (it ignores the more common meaning of "like never before"). But it's also a possibility that the writer isn't very good.

Answer (score 1):

It implies a higher degree of his brusqueness.

He's been brusque before, but he's never been this brusque.